# SSIS Data Conversion keeps switching back to Unicode

Tags: sql-server, unicode, ssis

In SSIS I am querying the Active Directory for a list of domain users.  The results (according to SSIS) are of data type 'Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT]'.

I am using the Data Conversion item from the SSIS Toolbox to translate all the field before inserting them into an SQL table.  I can go in and give each field an Output Alias and an output 'Data Type of String [DT_STR]' (I tried in the default options window and in the Advanced Properties window).  I click OK to save my settings, but the red X is still there saying it can't convert to Unicode and if I reopen the properties window all the Data Types are set back to Unicode.

Has anyone had this happen to them before?

Comment: can you change the DT_NTEXT to DT_WSTR instead of DT_STR in the Advanced Editor > Output Columns

Comment: If you go DT_NTEXT to DT_TEXT and then DT_TEXT to DT_STR, do you still have the same issue. [It works fine for me](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/04/active-directory-ssis-data-source.html) so I'm curious how it's not working for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unicode and non-unicode are incompatible types for conversion.  You need to use a derived column transformation to add a new column.  Use a data conversion in the expression:

```
(DT_STR, 20, 1252)[MyUnicodeCol]
```

Comment: This will work - but do I have to create a Derived Column element for each coloumn?

Comment: Yes.  Though that's pretty clunky.  I would suggest loading the data to a staging table and converting it in SQL downstream.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode and non-unicode are incompatible types for conversion. We need to convert that particular column as DT_WSTR from DT_NTEXT using Data conversion and then again we have convert it as DT_STR from DT_WSTR.

[Conversion from DT_NTEXT to DT_STR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFMXl.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers don't work, here is what I ended up with, from a SharePoint OData source. I was seeing the same behavior, the conversions resetting to default.

Using the Derived Column component, here is the Expression, with "Facility" being the field name and 10 being the length:

```
(DT_STR,10,1252)(DT_WSTR,10)Facility
```